# How to navigate to previous chats using Langchain much like ChatGPT does?

Tags: python, mongodb, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I am building a RAG-based ChatPDF application. The user can enter the PDF to generate the embeddings for, the embeddings are stored in a vector database (I am using Chromadb). Now all the basic chat functionality is working all fine along with the basic chat. The user asks questions and the model can remember the context all fine. But, it does as long as the user is in the current session. As soon as the session is closed, the model does not remember anything. I am using MongoDB for storing chat messages. The chat messages are being stored all fine in the database. But the model somehow does not remember previous context once the session is closed and restarted.

All I want is someway for the user to navigate back to the previous chats (much like ChatGPT) and that the model should remember what is being talked about in that particular window.

**EDITED**: I am sharing the entire script (the minimum runnable as per requested). This is actually an API so I will share the code accordingly.

```py
import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from collections import namedtuple
import uuid
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, APIRouter, Form, status
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA, LLMChain
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_mongodb import MongoDBChatMessageHistory
import chromadb
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

config = dotenv_values(".env")
chat_router = APIRouter()

Constants = namedtuple('Constants', ['OPEN_API_KEY', 'EMBEDDINGS_MODEL', 'CHAT_MODEL', 'MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING'])
configs = Constants(config["OPENAI_API_KEY"], config["EMBEDDINGS_MODEL"], config["CHAT_MODEL"], config['MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING'])

@chat_router.post("/trainpdf/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_upload_file(user_id: str = Form(...), pdf_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if not pdf_file.filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        return {"code": "400", "answer": "Only PDF files are allowed."}
    
    client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./trained_db")
    collection = client.get_or_create_collection("PDF_Embeddings")
    vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory="./trained_db", collection_name = collection.name, client = client)

    if check_for_existing_embeddings(pdf_file.filename, vectordb):
        return {"code": "400", "answer": "PDF EMBEDDINGS HAVE ALREADY BEEN GENERATED FOR THIS FILE. PLEASE PROVIDE A NEW FILE."}
    
    pdf_folder_path = f"Training_Data"
    os.makedirs(pdf_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    
    file_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, pdf_file.filename)
    with open(file_path, "wb") as temp_dest_file:
        temp_dest_file.write(await pdf_file.read())
        
    docs = read_docs(file_path, user_id)
    vectordb = generate_and_store_embeddings(docs, pdf_file, user_id)
    shutil.rmtree(pdf_folder_path, ignore_errors=True)

    if vectordb is None:
        return {"code": "400", "answer": "Error Occurred during Data Extraction from Pdf."}

    return {"code": "201", "answer": "PDF EMBEDDINGS GENERATED SUCCESSFULLY"}

@chat_router.post("/chatpdf/", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def pdf_chat(query_params: dict):
    user_id: str = query_params.get('user_id')
    query: str = query_params.get('query')
    session_id: str = user_id + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=configs.OPEN_API_KEY)
    client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./trained_db")
    collection = client.get_or_create_collection("PDF_Embeddings", embedding_function=embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(api_key=config["OPENAI_API_KEY"], model_name=configs.EMBEDDINGS_MODEL))
    vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory="./trained_db", embedding_function=embeddings, collection_name = collection.name)
    
    """Retrieve the documents relevant to the query and generate the response."""
    retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_type="mmr")
    relevant_docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query)

    user_specific_chat_memory = get_message_history(session_id)

    """Now I am going about adding chat history into two ways. Both have their share of problems.
       1. Adding chat history to the prompt template. This method takes in chat history as context. But it returns the error:
          ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'context'}
          Note that the error is returned once the user asks a second question after the chat model responds to the first one.
    """
    prompt_template = f"""You are engaged in conversation with a human,
                          your responses will be generated using a comprehensive long document as a contextual reference. 
                          You can summarize long documents and also provide comprehensive answers, depending on what the user has asked.
                          You also take context in consideration and answer based on chat history.
                          Chat History: {{context}}

                          Question: {{question}}

                          Answer :
                        """
    
    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])

    model = configs.CHAT_MODEL
    streaming_llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=configs.OPEN_API_KEY, model = model, temperature = 0.1, streaming=True)

    # use the streaming LLM to create a question answering chain
    qa_chain = load_qa_chain(
        llm=streaming_llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        prompt=PROMPT
    )
    question_generator_chain = LLMChain(llm=streaming_llm, prompt=PROMPT)
    qa_chain_with_history = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
        retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 3}, search_type='mmr'),
        combine_docs_chain=qa_chain,
        question_generator=question_generator_chain
    )
    response = qa_chain_with_history(
        {"question": query, "chat_history": user_specific_chat_memory.messages}
    )

    user_specific_chat_memory.add_user_message(response["question"])
    user_specific_chat_memory.add_ai_message(response["answer"])
    #return {"code": "200", "answer": response["answer"]}


    """2. Adding chat history to the memory. This saves the memory in a buffer which is passed to the retrieval chain. 
    But it forgets the entire context of the conversation once the session restarts (even though messages are being added to MongoDB).
    """
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history",
    chat_memory=user_specific_chat_memory,
    output_key="answer",
    return_messages=True
)
  
    qa_chain_with_history = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key = config["OPENAI_API_KEY"], model_name = model, temperature = 0.1),
    retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 3}, search_type='mmr'),
    memory = memory,
    chain_type="stuff"
)
    result = qa_chain_with_history.invoke({'question': query})

    user_specific_chat_memory.add_user_message(result["question"])
    user_specific_chat_memory.add_ai_message(result["answer"])

    return {"code": "200", "answer": result["answer"]}

def read_docs(pdf_file, user_id: str):
    pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_file)
    pdf_documents = pdf_loader.load()

    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(pdf_documents)
    
    now = datetime.now()
    for doc in documents:
        doc.metadata = {
            "user": user_id,
            "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),  
            "source": pdf_file.split("\\")[-1],
            'created_at': now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        }

    return documents

def generate_and_store_embeddings(documents, pdf_file, user_id):
    client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./trained_db")
    collection = client.get_or_create_collection("PDF_Embeddings",
                                                 embedding_function=embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(api_key=config["OPENAI_API_KEY"],
                                                                                                                model_name=configs.EMBEDDINGS_MODEL))
    
    try:
        vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
                    documents,
                    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=config["OPENAI_API_KEY"], model=configs.EMBEDDINGS_MODEL),
                    persist_directory='./trained_db',
                    collection_name = collection.name, 
                    client = client
                )
        vectordb.persist()
        data_associated_with_ids = vectordb.get(where={"source": 
                                               pdf_file.filename})

    except Exception as err:
        return None
    
    return vectordb

def check_for_existing_embeddings(pdf_filename, vectordb):
    doc_metadatas: list = vectordb.get(include=['metadatas'])['metadatas']
    results = [doc['source'].split("\\")[-1] for doc in doc_metadatas]
    if pdf_filename in list(set(results)):
        return True
    

def get_message_history(session_id: str) -> MongoDBChatMessageHistory:
    return MongoDBChatMessageHistory(connection_string=configs.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING, 
                                     session_id=session_id, 
                                     collection_name="Chat_History")
```

As mentioned in the pdf_chat function, there are two ways that I tried to incorporate chat history. The second method forgets the context after the session restarts (even for the same user) and the first method returns the error when the user follows up the model's *first* response with more queries (not on user's first question to the model). I will be quite satisfied if either of them works and remembers what the chat was about prior to the termination of the session, with date information of the particular conversation (i.e. somewhat mimics ChatGPT).

> ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'context'}

Comment: Please share the entire script for us to debug it. Thanks.